# How do I specifically check is a the slots all have a jackpot image for slot machine game

Tags: c#, winforms

**How do I also make it so that if all 3 slots have a jackpot image, the user wins 5x their bet**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;
```

```
namespace Slot_Machine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a, b, c, move, wins,losses, bid;
        int balance = 100;
```

**If the user clicks the quit button, the program ends**

```
        private void QuitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

**If the user presses the reset button, the game restarts**

```
        private void ResetBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Restart();
        }
```

**This function subtracts the bid from the balance before the slots start running**

```
        void Before_Game_Result()
        {
            bid = Convert.ToInt32(BidAmountTxt.Text);
            balance = balance - bid;
            BalanceLbl.Text = "Balance: $" + Convert.ToString(balance);
        }
```

**This function decides whether or not the user won their bid**

```
        void Game_Result()
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToInt32(a) == b && System.Convert.ToInt32(b) == c)
            {
                wins++;
                WinLbl.Text = "Wins: " + wins;
                bid = Convert.ToInt32(BidAmountTxt.Text);
                balance = balance + (bid * 2);
                BalanceLbl.Text = "Balance: $" + Convert.ToString(balance);
                BidBtn.Enabled = true;
                BidAmountTxt.Enabled = true;
                BidAmountTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            else 
            {
                if ((System.Convert.ToInt32(a) == b && System.Convert.ToInt32(b) != c) || (System.Convert.ToInt32(a) == c && System.Convert.ToInt32(b) != c) ||
                (System.Convert.ToInt32(b) == c && System.Convert.ToInt32(a) != c))
                {
                    wins++;
                    WinLbl.Text = "Wins: " + wins;
                    bid = Convert.ToInt32(BidAmountTxt.Text);
                    balance = balance + bid;
                    BalanceLbl.Text = "Balance: $" + Convert.ToString(balance);
                    BidBtn.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    losses++;
                    LossesLbl.Text = "Losses: " + losses;
                    BalanceLbl.Text = "Balance: $" + Convert.ToString(balance);
                    BidBtn.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
            

            if (balance <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You don't have any money!! SCRAM");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

**This function validates that the user enters a valid bid before pressing the bid button**

```
        private void BidBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(BidAmountTxt.Text =="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("input a bid first!!");
            }
            else
            {
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(BidAmountTxt.Text);
                bool success = false;
                if(x <= balance)
                {
                    success = true;
                }

                if(success)
                {
                    Before_Game_Result();

                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.Enabled = false;
                    BidBtn.Enabled = false;
                    BidAmountTxt.BackColor = Color.Black;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("INVALID - please enter a bid lower or equal to your balance");

                    BidAmountTxt.Clear();
                }



            }
        }
```

**This function runs the slots **

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            move++;
            if (move < 30)
            {

                a = rnd.Next(5);
                b = rnd.Next(5);
                c = rnd.Next(5);
                

                switch(a)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Slot1.Image = Properties.Resources.basketball3;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Slot1.Image = Properties.Resources.soccer_ball2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Slot1.Image = Properties.Resources.volleyball;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Slot1.Image = Properties.Resources.hockey_puck;
                        break;
                     
                }
                switch (b)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Slot2.Image = Properties.Resources.basketball3;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Slot2.Image = Properties.Resources.soccer_ball2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Slot2.Image = Properties.Resources.volleyball;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Slot2.Image = Properties.Resources.hockey_puck;
                        break;
                }
                switch (c)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Slot3.Image = Properties.Resources.basketball3;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Slot3.Image = Properties.Resources.soccer_ball2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Slot3.Image = Properties.Resources.volleyball;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Slot3.Image = Properties.Resources.hockey_puck;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    move = 0;
                
                    Game_Result();
                   
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: `System.Convert.ToInt32(a)` is redundant - `a` is already an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

There's lot of ways to do what you want. My take on this is that a little abstraction would go a long way. Starting with an ImageList where you can select pictures by index.

[image: image-list]

Assign it to the `ImageList` property of the controls (e.g. Label) you are using to display a slot "wheel".

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    labelJackpot.Visible= false;
    Slot1.ImageList = imageList;
    Slot2.ImageList = imageList;
    Slot3.ImageList = imageList;
}
```

---

Then you could abstract those index values to an enum.

```
enum SlotImage
{
    Jackpot,
    Basketball,
    SoccerBall,
    VolleyBall,
    HockeyPuck,
}
```

Which simplifies your "wheel spinner" in your timer tick handler:

```
Label[] Slots => new [] { Slot1, Slot2, Slot3 };
SlotImage[] SlotImages { get; } = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SlotImage)).Cast<SlotImage>().ToArray();
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    move++;
    if (move < 30)
    {
        foreach (var slot in Slots)
        {
            slot.ImageIndex= rnd.Next(SlotImages.Length);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        move = 0;

        // Probably goes in GameResult but here's how.
        var isJackpot = Slots.All(_ => ((SlotImage)_.ImageIndex).Equals(SlotImage.Jackpot));
        labelJackpot.Visible = isJackpot;

        Game_Result();
    }
}
```

Doing it in this manner would make the wheels comparable by `int`. So, one solution to your question is to use this System.Linq expression to see whether you've hit the jackpot.

```
isJackpot = Slots.All(_ => ((SlotImage)_.ImageIndex).Equals(SlotImage.Jackpot));
```

[image: jackpot]